# Anyone know the state of cocoa#?

Tags: c#, cocoa, macos, mono, monodevelop

Having just updated Mono to 2.6.3 (on OS X), I noticed in the installer that cocoa# 0.9.5 is also installed. However using MonoDevelop there are no cocoa# project templates by default, and I was wondering if anyone knew more about creating cocoa# apps.

If you goto the cocoa# page on the Mono site you can see it hasn't been updated since 2008, and cocoa-sharp.com has nothing on it at all now.

Has this project fallen by the wayside? If so, does anyone know of any alternatives? Winforms apps running under X11 are butt ugly and GTK# isn't much better.

To have a solid bridge between Mono and Cocoa would be ideal for developing OS X desktop apps, in the same way as the MonoTouch does with Cocoa Touch for the iPhone.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cocoa# doesnt seem to be maintained [anymore](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/cocoa-sharp/2010-January/001310.html), but take a look at [MonObjc](http://www.monobjc.net/).

Also interesting: [Heads-up: new Mono bindings for OSX.](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-osx/2010-March/002752.html)

Comment: Cracking answer. MonObjc looks just the ticket, I'll give it a spin. Also interesting to see what Miguel said there. All looking promising.